# Laravel eloquent where or

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

how i can create a query using the Eloquent and where array?
If where clause is "AND" it's ok, i'm use next code:

```
$whereArray = array(
          'start_time' => '123',
          'team1' => '123',
          'team2' => '123',
          'sport' => '123',
          'league' => '13',
                );
$rows = Table::where($whereArray)->get();
```

And the query is

```
select * from `table` where start_time ='123' and team1 = '123' and team2 = '123' and sport = '123' and league = '123'
```

But how i can use similar method and get "OR"??

```
select * from `table` where start_time ='123' OR team1 = '123' OR team2 = '123' OR sport = '123' OR league = '123'
```

Comment: Assign your query to a variable `$query`, loop over your `$whereArray` and add `->orWhere($key, "=", $value);`. Keep track of the index so you can do the first pass as a `->where()` and a `->orWhere()` for the others.

Comment: @ka_lin `whereIn()` will not work here. The code from Eric's answer will work just fine.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the array just need to use `orWhere` instead

```
$whereArray = array(
          'start_time' => '123',
          'team1' => '123',
          'team2' => '123',
          'sport' => '123',
          'league' => '13',
                );

$rows = Table::orWhere($whereArray)->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `orWhere` method.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queries#where-clauses

You can iterate over all your where's and add the orWhere clause:

```
$whereArray = array(
      'start_time' => '123',
      'team1' => '123',
      'team2' => '123',
      'sport' => '123',
      'league' => '13',
            );
$rows = DB::table('table');
foreach ($whereArray as $where) {
    $rows->orWhere($where);
}
$rows = $rows->get();
```

Also according to the Laravel docs:

> You may chain where constraints together as well as add or clauses to the query. The orWhere method accepts the same arguments as the where method

Meaning you can probably get away with just doing this:

```
Table::orWhere($whereArray)->get();
```